# How to sum and subtract one column value based on percentage in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @BalanceTblRec TABLE 
                       (
                           NetAmount decimal(18, 3), 
                           Percentage int, 
                           [Description] nvarchar(max)
                       )
DECLARE @BalanceTblPay TABLE 
                       (
                           NetAmount decimal(18, 3), 
                           Percentage int, 
                           [Description] nvarchar(max)
                       )

INSERT INTO @BalanceTblRec 
VALUES (21, 11, 'ReceiveReceipt'),
       (20, 11, 'ReceiveReceipt'),
       (20, 10, 'ReceiveReceipt'),
       (20, 20, 'ReceiveReceipt'), 
       (10, 10, 'ReceiveReceipt')

INSERT INTO @BalanceTblPay 
VALUES (10, 11, 'PayReceipt'),
       (10, 11, 'PayReceipt'), 
       (10, 2, 'PayReceipt'),
       (5, 15, 'PayReceipt'),
       (30, 10, 'PayReceipt'),
       (20, 10, 'PayReceipt')

;WITH MaPercentage AS
( 
    SELECT
        Percentage, 
        SUM(NetAmount) AS Net, 
        'Receive' AS Flag 
    FROM
        @BalanceTblRec 
    GROUP BY
        Percentage
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        Percentage, 
        SUM(NetAmount) AS Net, 
        'Pay' AS Flag 
    FROM
        @BalanceTblPay 
    GROUP BY 
        Percentage
)
SELECT * FROM MaPercentage
```

[image]

Now here I want subtract `net` from `net` based on `falg`, `receive - pay` based on percentage.

Like this:

```
Per Net         Flag
-----------------------
10  30.000 - 50 Receive
11  41.000 - 20 Receive
20  20.000      Receive
2   10.000      Pay
15  5.000       Pay
```

Comment: Subtracting `net` from `net` is zero... I think you need to reword that.

Comment: subtract net from net means its same column but based on same percentage and flag (that is receive - pay)subtraction is required as you can see results that i want in last section

Comment: Just as a side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **completely unsupported** (out of even extended support) by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Thank you for your note, i am afraid of upgrade as lot of change may not work in later version of sql, can you confirm its completely save to upgrade from 2008 to latest version not syntax or any other compatible issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
DECLARE @BalanceTblRec TABLE (NetAmount decimal(18,3), Percentage int, [Description] nvarchar(max))
DECLARE @BalanceTblPay TABLE (NetAmount decimal(18,3), Percentage int, [Description] nvarchar(max))

insert into @BalanceTblRec values (21, 11, 'ReceiveReceipt'),(20, 11, 'ReceiveReceipt'),(20, 10, 'ReceiveReceipt'),(20, 20, 'ReceiveReceipt'), (10, 10, 'ReceiveReceipt')
insert into @BalanceTblPay values (10, 11, 'PayReceipt'),(10, 11, 'PayReceipt'),(10, 2, 'PayReceipt'),(5, 15, 'PayReceipt'),(30, 10, 'PayReceipt') ,(20, 10, 'PayReceipt')


;WITH MaPercentage as ( 
select Percentage, sum(NetAmount) as Net, 'Receive' as Flag from @BalanceTblRec group by Percentage
union all
select Percentage, -sum(NetAmount) as Net, 'Pay' as Flag from @BalanceTblPay group by Percentage
)

select 
  Percentage, 
  abs(sum(net)) as SumNet,
  case when sum(net) > 0 then 'Receive' 
  else 'Pay'
  end as Flag
from MaPercentage 
group by Percentage
```

Just changed the sign in the Pays and sum groupping by percentage.

Comment: Yes exactly same results i wanted, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to FULL JOIN the receivements with the payments.

```
;WITH RCV AS (
  select Percentage, sum(NetAmount) as Net
  from @BalanceTblRec
  group by Percentage
)
, PAY AS (
  select Percentage, sum(NetAmount) as Net
  from @BalanceTblPay 
  group by Percentage
)
SELECT 
COALESCE(r.Percentage, p.Percentage) AS Percentage, 
ABS(COALESCE(r.Net, 0) - COALESCE(p.Net, 0)) AS Net, 
(CASE 
 WHEN (COALESCE(r.Net, 0) - COALESCE(p.Net, 0)) < 0 THEN 'Pay'
 ELSE 'Receive'
 END) AS Flag
FROM RCV r
FULL JOIN PAY p ON p.Percentage = r.Percentage
```